# How to create a multi data center Cassandra cluster in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, kubernetes-statefulset

I have created a Cassandra cluster in Kubernetes with a `service.yaml` and `statefulset.yaml`. However I am having a bit of trouble creating a multi data center Cassandra cluster in the Kubernetes space. I want to create a cluster in two data centers with 3 nodes in each.

I have seen articles about adding multiple seed nodes (one in each data center) in the yaml and tried that but it errors out. I have also seen articles on how to create a multi DC cluster of Cassandra but not in Kubernetes but I need to create it in Kubernetes.

Comment: Are you aware of k8ssandra.io ? Because after having your 2 DC  you still need the monitoring, administration and tooling. K8ssandra is a all in one Free system. Here is a tutorial https://docs.k8ssandra.io/install/local/multi-cluster-helm/

Comment: Also, this isn't about programming and will likely be moved to https://dba.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen articles about adding multiple seed nodes (one in each data center) in the yaml and tried that but it errors out.

Yes.  That is the way.  I'd have a look at *why* this errors out.

I've built multi-DC Cassandra clusters in K8s before.  As K8s presents difficulties with multi-DC itself, it was across two different K8s clusters.

When I did it, we had an interface that abstracted the port/address forwarding aspect.  But essentially I allowed public ingress on 7000, and then the seed list entries from the other DC worked.

**TL;DR;**

You're on the right path.  Just make sure that one DC can see the other on the network, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a yaml file, configured two cassandra address, but I follow the Spring-data for cassandra in the document, created two cassandraConfig, of course, their names are not the same, but when I start my application, reported an error create bean wrong I do not know what to do now. I don't know what to do now. The requirement is to write the same data to two different cassandra datapaths.